# ¿Cómo se ejecutan las funciones en un Bucle infinito?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy haciendo un juego con **pygame** para clase de informática en bachillerato. Tengo montado un while True y ahí dentro metí lo siguiente:

```
if victoria == 30:
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("victory.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    surface.blit(victoria, (0,0))
    vbx = 0
    vby = 0
```

Cuando se cumplían los requisitos para la victoria la canción que tenía que sonar, al estar metida dentro del bucle, empezaba a sonar 30 veces por segundo.

Luego me dí cuenta que si **todo lo que he puesto en ese if** lo defino previamente como una función y dentro del while lo dejo así:

```
if victoria == 30:
    win()
```

la canción empezaba a sonar una sola vez, como debe ser.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿por qué el **while True** sólo lee una vez la función en vez de leerlo 30 veces por segundo como lo puse anteriormente?

Comment: No debería haber diferencia alguna entre tener el código directamente metido en el bucle, o sacarlo a una función y llamarlo desde el bucle. La diferencia de comportamiento tiene que deberse a alguna otra cosa que hayas cambiado. Revisa el código.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta:

```
tamano = event.size
```

Prueba validando el **if** de esta forma:

```
if victoria == tamano:
   win()
```